# Model relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database, django-database

I am new to Django and databases and after reading the Django documentation on models I have the following question:
Let's say I have 3 models: VehicleName, CarManufacturer and TruckManufacturer. I am trying to create a database relationship where CarMaunfacturer has many VehicleNames and also TruckManufacturer has many VehicleNames. What is the relationship here and how to define it in Django? Is it as simple as define a models.ForeignKey(VehicleName) in both CarManufacturer and TruckManufacturer?
Thanks.

```
from django.db import models

class CarManufacturer(models.Model):
    vehicle_name = models.ForeignKey(VehicleName)  # IS THIS CORRECT???
    # ...
    pass

class TruckManufacturer(models.Model):
    vehicle_name = models.ForeignKey(VehicleName)  # IS THIS CORRECT???
    # ...
    pass

class VehicleName(models.Model):
    # ...
```

Comment: I think the property is misnamed. It seems to me that you are saying a Vehicle object is a property of a CarManufacturer/TruckManufacturer called manufacturer, when it's rather one of the items being manufactured. You kind of need to tell us what the relationship is that you want to build.

Comment: You are right, it should be vehicle_name instead of manufacturer (I fixed it in the question), but even then I am not sure that my code is correct: I want CarMaunfacturer to have many vehicle_names and also TruckManufacturer to have many vehicle_names.

Comment: Are there any differences in the database level i.e. in the number/types of fields on `CarManufacturer` and `TruckManufacturer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you're describing:

> I am trying to create a database relationship where CarMaunfacturer has many VehicleNames and also TruckManufacturer has many VehicleNames

You'd create a nullable foreign key on VehicleName to both of your Manufacturer models:

```
class CarManufacturer(models.Model):
    # field definitions here

class TruckManufacturer(models.Model):
    # field definitions here

class VehicleName(models.Model):
    car_manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(CarManufacturer, blank=True, null=True)
    truck_manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(TruckManufacturer, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, instances of `CarManufacturer` or `TruckManufacturer` can get the names via the `vehiclename_set` attribute.

For a more advanced design, I would probably try to abstract the shared manufacturer behavior into a single model, then use multi-table inheritance:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # shared car and truck manufacturer fields go here

class CarManufacturer(Manufacturer):
    # car manufacturer specific fields go here

class TruckManufacturer(Manufacturer):
    # truck manufacturer specific fields go here

class VehicleName(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
```

See the [multi-table inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) for full details.

Comment: Thanks. Also, if for instance, I remove certain "car manufacturer" from CarManufacturer table, all the "vehicle names" in VehicleName table that correspond to that car manufacturer will be removed automatically. Am I correct?

Comment: By default, yes.  "When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE – in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are understanding the manufacturer to vehicle relationship property. What I think you are trying to show is that a certain `Vehicle` belongs to a certain `manufacturer`.

This type of relationship would actually be defined in the `Vehicle` class, as a foreign key, called `manufacturer`, in the `Vehicle` class.

In the case you are defining many vehicles under a manufacturer, you just need to rename the property to `car_model` or something of the like and you should be fine.

I think you have the understanding mapped out well enough. Just remember that foreign keys are only a property of one table, and say nothing about the other table itself until the relationship is established there also.

If you're working with a larger relationship, with multiple objects, you should look into using the Many-to-many field described in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

They have an example that shows how an Articles have many Publications:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

Comment: I am trying to create a database relationship where CarMaunfacturer has many VehicleNames and also TruckManufacturer has many VehicleNames. I am trying to undersrtand what would be the relationship here and how to implement it.